Am I soft-locked in Castlevania II: Simon's Quest?
I'm playing through Castlevania II: Simon's Quest at the moment and I seem to have become a little stuck around the Bodley Mansion area. I checked this walkthrough and it seems I have come to this area sooner than I should have. I have been through Bodley Mansion and retrieved Dracula's nail; however, this is only the second mansion I have beaten and according to the guide it should have been the 4th. I also have Dracula's rib but I still only have the thorn whip (no wonder many of the enemies are starting to seem rather 'spongy' ...).
According to the guide, the way forwards is to go to the west from the Manor, down through a hidden passage and across a swamp, which will take me to what is supposed to be the 5th and final mansion (Laruba). However, that would seem to be taking me even further onwards, where my puny thorn whip will be even less effective.
Can anyone tell me if I am softlocked in the game? Is there any way to get back from here to the earlier areas? Even if I'm not softlocked, is going forwards under-powered going to get increasingly more painful and unpleasant?
I would appreciate any advice!

Following this map from the Wiki, it seems the only way is to get to the Mansion of the Ring and from there, leave for the Camilla Cemetery and therefore back to Aljiba, because the other way, "access from the East Bridge to the "Mansion of the Rib" was removed." in the final game.
The guide you link does say how to get back to Camilla Cemetery... in the "Dracula's Castle" section:

You'll be back out the front of Laruba Mansion. Now, if you go left from here, you'd get to another long stretch of poisoned water. If you were to wade left through this, it would take you to the unseen eastern part of Camilla's Cemetery,

So you just have to be able to make it to the front of the Mansion of the Ring / Laruba Mansion, then jump across a "gap and ledge".

Thanks for your answer, although I already tried that route before and it doesn't seem to work. According to this wiki, the East Bridge leads to the Denis Marsh, which is a dead end. It looks like it should go back to the Rib Mansion, but there seems to be no way to get there.

@Time4Tea - Thanks! I forgot to note that the path was removed in the final game. Thankfully there is a way to backtrack, but you have to be able to reach the front of Laruba Mansion first. Good luck!

Yes, it seems like a curious decision, as it would seem to be a good place to put a 1-way path to allow the player to get back to the earlier areas. I wonder why they just made it a dead-end?

Your revised solution does work - I have now verified it. You can get back to Aljiba from Laruba Mansion, as long as you have some laurels to help get past the poisonous swamp water. And you can buy laurels in Doina, I believe. So, there's no soft lock.

@Time4Tea - Yep, your linked guide says so on the Laurels: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/nes/587179-castlevania-ii-simons-quest/faqs/78511/laruba-mansion-draculas-ring - Town of Doina [...] you can buy Laurels if you need them.
